# Why i used getX not work in flutter ListView?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

> when I tap containter and update selectedIndex equal current index, but it not will update.

```
class HomeController extends GetxController {

  final RxList<PurineTypeModel> dataSource = RxList();
  final selectedIndex = 0.obs;
}
```

```
Obx(() {
          return ListView.builder(
              cacheExtent: 30,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemBuilder: (c, index) {
                print("refresh?? $index");
                return GestureDetector(child: Container(
                  width: 100,
                  color: controller.selectedIndex.value == index ? Colors.red : Colors.green,
                  child: Text(
                      controller.selectedIndex.string),
                ), onTap: () {
                  controller.selectedIndex.value = 1;
                },);
              },
              itemCount: controller.dataSource.length);
        })
```

Comment: Can i see , where and how ,you have initialised the controller? because your code looks fine.

Comment: You should assign dynamic index while tapping on container  like this `controller.selectedIndex.value = index ;`   but you have assigned 1, why ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the GestureDetector also in an Obx, so like this:

```
Obx(() {
  return ListView.builder(
      cacheExtent: 30,
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemBuilder: (c, index) {
        print("refresh?? $index");
        return Obx(() =>
            GestureDetector(child: Container(
              width: 100,
              color: controller.selectedIndex.value == index ? Colors
                  .red : Colors.green,
              child: Text(
                  controller.selectedIndex.string),
            ), onTap: () {
              controller.selectedIndex.value = 1;
            },));
      },
      itemCount: controller.dataSource.length);
})
```

Because the outer Obx only observes `controller.dataSource.length`

Answer (score 0):

```
onTap: () {
                  controller.selectedIndex.value = index;
                },);
```

setup index element not 1
the controller is initialized how?

Comment: It is my test code, I fixed it use controller.selectedIndex.value = 1; and last call controller.dataSource.refresh()